# Does performing a System Refresh keep these folders?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

Alright, let's make this simple.

I'm really contemplating performing a system refresh. What I've been looking for all over is if the process keeps some certain folders. Namely my Documents, Pictures, Videos, Downloads, and Desktop folders. There's some real valuable stuff in there, and I really want to know if refreshing my PC will keep these intact.

Also, there is an application located at C:\Pesterchum that I would like to keep intact. Should I back it up, then copy it back into its original location after the refresh? Or will it be left untouched?

Comment: Personal files are not deleted during a refresh the description even says this.  You should have a backup of this stuff no matter what

Comment: I know that, but I'd just like to be completely sure that those folders are saved.

Comment: Back then up then you will be sure, but, yes they won't be touched in fact no files will actually be removed system files will be restored

Comment: The real question is, 'Does performing a system refresh ever fix anything?'...The answer is NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source [How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc):

> If you're having problems with your PC, you can try to refresh, reset, or restore it. **Refreshing your PC reinstalls Windows and keeps your personal files and settings**. It also keeps the apps that came with your PC and the apps you installed from the Windows Store. Resetting your PC reinstalls Windows but deletes your files, settings, and apps—except for the apps that came with your PC. Restoring your PC is a way to undo recent system changes you've made.